# PageBlock Table Column Value Trimming

Tags: visualforce, css, list-view, pageblocktable

I have used the below code to show a list view. How can I apply text trimming (ellipse) for the description column to avoid multiple?

```
<apex:listViews type="contact"/ >
```

1. Is there any CSS style to achieve this?
2. Can we make the column header resized by using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question One:**

Rows that result from the [`apex:listViews`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_listViews.htm) component (not the header row) are assigned the `dataRow` class, and the children elements can either be [`td`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) or [`th`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th), so we can use the following CSS snippet to set the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property to [`ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#ellipsis) if the "Description" column is the third column:

```
.dataRow > *:nth-child(3) {
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Answer to Question Two:**

The header row is assigned the `headerRow` class, so we can use the [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) property to increase the font size of the header column, or we can change the [`padding-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom) or [`padding-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top) properties to manipulate the height of the header row relative to the contents of the header cells.

```
.headerRow > th {
    font-size: 1em !important;
    padding-bottom: 8px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
```

Furthermore, we can change the [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) of individual header columns (the following example changes the width of the third column) using the following example:

```
.headerRow > th:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 500px;
}
```